# Doubt in an alternate solution to an IMO problem from 1987

Tags: functional-equations

Consider the following problem from 1987 IMO
Show that there is no function $f:\mathbb N→\mathbb N$
Such that

$f(f(n))=n+1987$

In the book that I was referring the solution is given as follows:

"
We show that infact there is no function that satisfies this condition

$f(f(n))=n+k$ where k is odd

Assume such an $f$ exists. Then $f(n+k)=f(n)+k$ for all n in N and
$f(n-k)=f(n)-k$ for all $n\geq k$
Consider $g(n)=f(n)-k$

Verify that $g(f(n))=n$ for all n and $f(g(n))=n$ for all $f(n) \geq k$

Consider the sets $A=${$n|0\leq n<k$ and $f(n)<k$}
and $B=${$n|0\leq n<k$ and $f(n)\geq k$}

Show that there is a bijection between A and B and conclude

$|A|=|B|$

This implies $2|A|=k$ and this forces a contradiction
"

The only part I am having trouble is finding such a bijection

Can someone please help

Here $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all natural numbers and 0

Comment: (Tip: Use `\mid` rather than `|` when it means "such that" or "divides" rather than half of an absolute value or determinant function. `\{n | -1 < n\}` gives $\{n | -1 < n\}$ and `\{n \mid -1 < n\}` gives $\{n \mid -1 < n\}$ with better spacing.)

Comment: @aschepler thank you
In fact I wanted to write n is greater that or equal to 0 but I don't know how to do that

Comment: `\geq` or `\ge` gives $\geq$ and `\geqslant` gives the nicer looking $\geqslant$.  Similarly `\leq`, `\le` and `\leqslant`.

Comment: `\leq` and `\geq`. See the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), point 11.

Comment: Since $g$ and $f$ were shown to be inverses of each other (on suitable domains containing $A$ and $B$, respectively) in the preceding line, trying to show that the bijection is given by  $f\colon A\to B$ with inverse $g\colon B\to A$ looks suggestive ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you, that worked